# How to calculate the position and size of a shape in OpenXML to display in WPF like the same in PPTx

Tags: wpf, openxml

I have a simple shape in PPTx

and I saw and got Its position in Openxml

```
 <a:xfrm>
 <a:off x="1447800" y="1066800" />
  <a:ext cx="3886200" cy="990600" />
</a:xfrm>
```

I got out this values

but I don't known how to get with, height, and coordinate (left, top) of shape in Open xml to show in wpf with the same with, height and position.

Answer (score 5):

Divide those values by 12700 for point values (what WPF uses). So it would be:

- **x = 114** (a:off@x = 1447800/12700)
- **y = 84** (a:off@y = 1066800/12700)
- **width = 306** (a:ext@cx = 3886200/12700)
- **height = 78** (a:ext@cy = 990600/12700)

Comment: Thank you Todd Main. Please tell me know what is 12700 number

Comment: The measurement for most Office dimensions is in EMU (English metric units). It is because they are integers and therefore faster to work with than floats. 1 inch = 914400 EMU, 1 point = 12700 EMU. EMU isn't always used however - for example, font sizes are exactly the same as in WPF, e.g. 10pt font = 10pt font.