# How to calculate the position of a shape in a word file？

Tags: excel, ms-word, openxml

In word file, there is a 'group' with a width of 200 pixels and a height of 175 pixels, with a straight line in it. I have got the information about the group and the line, how can I calculate the position of the line in the group?

Group Info:

```
<a:xfrm>
    <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
    <a:ext cx="1904999" cy="1664918"/>
    <a:chOff x="0" y="0"/>
    <a:chExt cx="1885532" cy="881773"/>
</a:xfrm>
```

Line Info:

```
<a:xfrm rot="16200000" flipH="1">
    <a:off x="356651" y="84236"/>
    <a:ext cx="0" cy="713302"/>
</a:xfrm>
```

I tried to calculate the result as follows, but it seems to be different from the actual situation.

x = 356651 / 1885532 * 200 = 37.830278

y = 84236 / 881773 * 175 = 16.71779471

The result looks neither like the rotated nor the original position.
I'm confused.

Although I checked Microsoft's official documentation, unfortunately, the correct result cannot be obtained according to the description of the documentation.

Also this has a similar question([How to calculate the position and size of a shape in OpenXML to display in WPF like the same in PPTx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594689/how-to-calculate-the-position-and-size-of-a-shape-in-openxml-to-display-in-wpf-l)), but also doesn't have the answer I'm looking for.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The values in the attributes are in EMU (English Metric Unit). If you want it's value in pixels, divide by 9525. If you want it's value in points, divide by 12700. If you want it's value in inches, divide by 9144000. The issue you may be having is that the line is rotated and also flipped. You wound have to account for those transformations.